# filter table data using cascading drop-down in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to filter table using cascading drop-down in angularjs.  It works for parent drop-down but does not work for child drop-down properly.

This is my controller code:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {

GetSupportData();
$scope.setSelected = function () {enter code here
if ($scope.lastSelected) {
$scope.lastSelected.selected = '';
}
this.selected = 'rowSelect';
$scope.lastSelected = this;
}
$scope.predicate = '-Date';


function GetSupportData() {
blockUI();
$http({
method: 'Get',
url: '/Home/GetSupportData',
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.Support = data.SupportData;


enablePinning: true;
unblockUI();
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
unblockUI();
$scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
});
 }


});
```

And this is my view code:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in QCQA | filter: System.SYSTEM_TITLE:ignoreNullComparator | filter: Moduledata.MODULE_TITLE:ignoreNullComparator | orderBy:predicate:reverse" class="{{data.ISSUE_STATUS}} {{data.DAY_COUNT}} {{selected}}" data-ng-click="setSelected(this)" style="min-height: 25px">


<div id="StateSectionsBar" class="divStateSectionsBar" style="height: 30px">
<div>
<div class="divControlsRow">
<div class="divDesc">System:</div>
<div class="divControls">
<select data-ng-model="System.SYSTEM_TITLE"  data-ng-options="s.SYSTEM_ID as s.SYSTEM_TITLE for s        in sysList" data-ng-change="GetModule()">
 <option value="">----------------------All--------------------</option>
 </select>            
 </div>
 <div class="divDesc">Module:</div>
 <div class="divControls">

 <select  data-ng-model="Moduledata.MODULE_TITLE" data-ng-disabled="!ModuleData" data-ng-options="m.MODULE_ID as m.MODULE_TITLE for m in ModuleData">
 <option value="">----------------------All--------------------</option>
 </select>

 </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: "but does not work for child drop-down properly" - consider editing your question to describe what happens (or doesn't happen).

Comment: when i click on "Moduledata" drop-down then it load data properly but when i click again on all(option) of 'System" drop-down then it does not show all data in table

Comment: Now edit that into the question, not all people read comments :-)

Comment: when i click on "Moduledata" drop-down then it load data properly but when i click again on all(option) of 'System" drop-down then it does not show all data in table

Comment: see about 10 cm above this comment, you see "share edit flag". click on "edit" and there improve your question, this will get you faster answers.

Comment: 10 cm = 3.93701 inches